# Awk - Print row if number is between column 1 and column 2

Tags: awk

I have a file with data formatted like this.

**Input file**

```
"1930","1946","FOO","BAR","GREEN"
"1949","1962","FOO","BAR","BLUE"
"1970","1980","FOO","BAR","YELLOW"
```

Numbers are not continuous, with some major gap sometimes. I would like to have the following matching row returned for a number that matches between the two first columns.

Example:

**Desired output for Number 1952**

```
1952:
"1949","1962","FOO","BAR","BLUE"
```

AWK or any bash scripting will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -F',' -v y=1952 'BEGIN{print y":"} {line=$0;gsub("\"","");} $1+0<=y && y<=$2+0 {print line}' file
1952:
"1949","1962","FOO","BAR","BLUE"
```

#### How it works

- `-F','`

  This sets the field separator to a comma.
- `-v y=1952`

  This defines an awk variable `y` with value 1952.
- `BEGIN{print y":";}`

  This prints out the header line.
- `line=$0; gsub("\"","")`

  This saves the original line as `line`.  It then removes the double quotes from the fields.
- `$1+0<=y && y<=$2+0 {print line}`

  If the value of `y` is between the values of the first and second columns, then print the original `line`.

  In the above line, zero is added to the numbers in the first and second columns.  This assures that awk treats those columns as numbers, not strings, and consequently does numeric, not string, comparisons.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Header and the delimiters was not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

With a more specific field separator a compact `awk` solution could be:

```
awk -F '(","|^"|"$)' -v d=1952 'd>=$2 && d<=$3'
```

Notes: Due to the chosen field separator here fields `$2` and `$3` are the respective fields. End quote (`"$`) has been added for a more general case that any line could have just two dates with no further data. Header is omitted as noted in the other comment; otherwise add `BEGIN{print d":"}`. The main part `d>=$2 && d<=$3` is self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter `awk`:

```
$ awk -F\" -vn=1952 '$2<=n && $4>=n' file
"1949","1962","FOO","BAR","BLUE"
```

The above will work with most modern `awk`, which based on `nawk`.

With implementation derived from original `awk`, like `oawk`, you need:

```
oawk -F\" 'BEGIN{n=1952}$2<=n && $4>=n'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk ' y>=nq($1) && y<=nq($2)
      function nq(s) {return gensub(/^"|"$/,"","g",s)}
    ' F=, y=1951 file
```

Or if you prefer, you can put the variables `F` abn `y` immediately after `awk`, instead of as a parameter

```
awk -F, -vy=1951
```